# How to use Spring Cloud Gateway for both APIs and UI

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using Spring Cloud Gateway in front of APIs and UI. I want the UI paths to trigger the oidc flow where they are presented with the login screen from keycloak and so on. But when the APIs are called, I want the resource server flow. Can I configure Spring Cloud Gateway to treat both routes different. If yes, how?

I followed the following tutorial to setup API security jwt flow and I am using Keycloak as the Idp:
https://blog.devops.dev/spring-cloud-gateway-oauth2-security-with-keycloak-jwt-tokens-and-securing-it-with-https-ssl-2166d8009531

Wherever I've looked it's one or the other in most of the tutorials available on the internet.

Comment: Is your UI writen with a server-side rendering framework (Thymeleaf, JSP,...) or is it a SPA (Angular, React, Vue,...)?

Comment: Hi @ch4mp, It's an SPA (Vue3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither *OIDC* nor *resource server* are *flows*. You are probably referring respectively to `authorization_code` flow for end-users *login* and requests authorization with `Bearer` token (which can be done whatever the *flow* used by the client to get tokens).

As per [latest recommandations](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390), you shouldn't configure your SPA frontend as an OAuth2 client. You should use sessions (and CSRF protection), not tokens, to authorize requests from SPAs to your backend, but very few tutorials follow current best practices when it comes to OAuth2 and SPAs (or mobile apps).

As you already figured out, `spring-cloud-gateway` can be configured as an OAuth2 client with `oauth2Login`. It can also be configured with `TokenRelay` filter on the routes to your resource servers to replace the session cookie with the access token in session before forwarding the request.

I wrote [a tutorial on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2) with `spring-cloud-gateway` configured as BFF for SPAs (Angular, React and Vue).

What is not in this tutorial anymore is the case where you need to route both SPAs (authorized with sessions) and OAuth2 clients (authorized with tokens) through the gateway. The 2nd case is legit when you have a service running on a server you trust and itself configured as a confidential client (for instance a batch with client_credentials or a Thymeleaf UI).

In such a case, you may define differents routes on your gateway redirecting to the same resource-servers:

- one (let's say `/bff/v1/**`) with `oauth2client` and the `TokenRelay` filter for SPAs authorized with sessions. Such requests should be processed in an OAuth2 client filter-chain.
- another one (let's say `/resource-server/v1/**`) transparent to security (neither `oauth2client` nor `TokenRelay` filter) for OAuth2 clients authorized with tokens. You may define another "stateless" filter-chain for such requests, to save the resources consumed to maintain sessions.

See this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77396527/spring-boot-backend-as-oauth2-client-and-resource-server-with-session-cookies-re/77397461#77397461) if you need instructions to configure more than one security filter-chain in a single Spring application (one with sessions and `oauth2Login` for `/bff/**` routes and another without sessions nor login for `/resource-server/**` routes)

Comment: Thanks @ch4mp, this is super helpful. I understand the bit about sessions. But in case of API only clients, what should be the behavior. E.g, an api client with API key my_api_client_1. I don't want them to be forwarded to a login screen. Instead, they should generate an access token and then call the gateway with that token. How can I have these two behaviors in a single implementation of the gateway.

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: you rock... thanks for taking the time to answer in detail. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Forgot to write that BFF tutorials already have two filter-chains (with abd without login & sessions) and routes with and without TokenRelay. The aim is different (save the resources used to maintain session when it is useless), but the routes to resource servers for OAuth2 clients would be defined the same as the one to UI assets.

Comment: @ch4mp what would be the best practice for the below scenario?
I have seen your BFF tutorial and it is amazing but I have one question. The BFF tutorial has only a specific redirection URL. But for me I have multiple clients accessing this gateway (Angular for WEB and Flutter for mobile) they should redirect accordingly. The API contract is the same for both web and mobile. In such a scenario what would be the best practice you recommend?

Comment: Your mobile application should implement modern deep links (Android "app-links" or iOS "universal links") which should be valid URIs inside your web app (Angular). So actually, redirecting only to your Angular app shouldn't be a problem.  When  this happens on a device with your app installed, the user should be redirected to the app (provided that you correctly validated the links). One caveat thought, there are few native HTTP clients which handle session & CSRF cookies transparently. Dart `http` package for flutter doesn't. I have a working sample fixing that, but not published yet.