# Spring Boot backend as OAuth2 client and resource server with session cookies returns 403

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

A Spring Boot application based on Spring Boot 3.x and Spring Security 6.x shall be setup like this:

- It shall act as a confidential OAuth2 client interacting with an IDP like Keycloak.
- It shall also act as a resource server.
- Upon successful login, it shall issue a session cookie to the client instead of the token.
- When a client requests any resource with a valid session cookie, it shall "unwrap" the token from the session and use it for the protected resources.

This is my current security configuration:

```java
@Order(1)
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain clientFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    return httpSecurity
            .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(matcherRegistry -> matcherRegistry.requestMatchers("/api/user/current").authenticated())
            .oauth2Login(loginConfigurer -> loginConfigurer.defaultSuccessUrl(applicationConfiguration.getFrontendRedirectUrl(), true))
            .exceptionHandling(exceptionHandlingConfigurer -> exceptionHandlingConfigurer.authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)))
            .logout(logoutConfigurer -> logoutConfigurer.logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler()))
            .build();
}

@Order(2)
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain resourceServerFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    return httpSecurity
            .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(matcherRegistry -> matcherRegistry.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .oauth2ResourceServer(configurer -> configurer.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
            .build();
}
```

The login itself works, i.e. Keycloak issues a token, the application retrieves it and issues a `JSESSION` cookie to the client.

When requesting a resource like `/api/test-data`, this should be secured by the 2nd bean but the client always retrieves a 403 (Forbidden) and I don't know why.

Even if I change the 2nd bean to `matcherRegistry.anyRequest().permitAll()` the client gets a 403.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use multiple login pages one for admin and the other one for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75298001/how-to-use-multiple-login-pages-one-for-admin-and-the-other-one-for-user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your first security filter-chain does not contain a `securityMatcher` to limit which requests it should process, the second is never tried.

The easiest way to fix that is probably to reverse the order (put the `resourceServerFilterChain` first) and define a `securityMatcher` selecting requests with an `Authorization` header starting with `Bearer` .

```java
@Order(1)
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain resourceServerFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    return httpSecurity
            .securityMatcher((HttpServletRequest request) -> {
                return Optional.ofNullable(request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)).map(h -> {
                    return h.toLowerCase().startsWith("bearer ");
                }).orElse(false);
            })
            .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .sessionManagement(sm -> sm.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(matcherRegistry -> matcherRegistry.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .oauth2ResourceServer(configurer -> configurer.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
            .build();
}

@Order(2)
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain clientFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    return httpSecurity
            .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
            // Never disable CSRF protection when sessions are enabled
            // Following is the conf for a SPA (like your Vue app)
            .csrf(csrf(configurer -> {
                // see https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/exploits.html#_i_am_using_angularjs_or_another_javascript_framework
                final var delegate = new XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();
                delegate.setCsrfRequestAttributeName("_csrf");
                configurer.csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).csrfTokenRequestHandler(delegate::handle);
                httpSecurity.addFilterAfter(new CsrfCookieFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
            })
            .authorizeHttpRequests(matcherRegistry -> matcherRegistry.requestMatchers("/api/user/current").authenticated())
            .oauth2Login(loginConfigurer -> loginConfigurer.defaultSuccessUrl(applicationConfiguration.getFrontendRedirectUrl(), true))
            .exceptionHandling(exceptionHandlingConfigurer -> exceptionHandlingConfigurer.authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)))
            .logout(logoutConfigurer -> logoutConfigurer.logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler()))
            .build();
}

private static final class CsrfCookieFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException,
            IOException {
        CsrfToken csrfToken = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
        // Render the token value to a cookie by causing the deferred token to be loaded
        csrfToken.getToken();

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

##### Notes

Never disable CSRF protection when sessions are enabled: **your OAuth2 client filter-chain with `oauth2Login` needs sessions and, as a consequence, CSRF protection**.

Do not configure OAuth2 client with `oauth2Login` and resource server in a single security filter-chain (as advised in another answer): security requirements are too different (`oauth2Login` security relies on sessions and need CSRF protection, resource servers rely on tokens and can be stateless)

Are you sure that you need the resource server filter-chain at all? Otherly asked, **do you have OAuth2 confidential clients running on server you trust sending requests to your API?** All the requests from browser using `oauth2Login` will be authorized with sessions (not tokens), and it is perfectly fine like that. Browsers need a framework like Angular, React or Vue, configured as public OAuth2 client to send requests authorized with tokens and [this is now discouraged](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390).

I personally configure my REST APIs solely as resource servers. The UI always is in a separate application. In the case of server-side rendered frameworks (Thymeleaf, JSF, etc.), the app serving the UI is configured as OAuth2 client. In the case of single page applications (Angular, React, Vue, etc.) or mobile apps, I use a backend for frontend (`spring-cloud-gateway` with `oauth2Login` and the `TokenRelay` filter to replace the session cookie from the frontend, with the access token in session, before forwarding the request to a resource server).

You could be interested in [this starter I wrote](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master#ease-openid-configuration--tests-in-spring-boot-3) which eases OAuth2 security configuration (even in the case where you want both client and resource server filter-chains in the same app). This repo also contains quite a few tutorials, including one with the BFF pattern.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. I will definitely check out your samples and starter, but there are some questions. 1) I read about the `securityMatcher` but I still don't get the difference to `authorizeHttpRequests`. 2) As to your question: The Spring backend itself is the confidential OAuth2 client and yes, I have a Vue SPA which shall only interact using the session cookie. We have another setup with Spring Cloud Gateway working fine, but here we wanted to avoid the need for another gateway and "integrate" something like the TokenRelay filter. Maybe we could use a chat room for details?

Comment: The basic intentation of my setup is: Instead of using Spring Cloud Gateway with a TokenRelay filter and a separate resource server, combine this functionality in a single servlet application which acts as both, OAuth2Client and resource server. But maybe there is some flaw in my understanding.

Comment: My answer is intended to cover the case where the app is both client with login and resource server (without the need for a gateway with TokenRelay filter). It is similar to what is in [this tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_ui) (as opposed to the BFF one). If your Vue app uses the `oauth2Login`, then it won't send requests with tokens and you should probably remove the resource server filter-chain (it won't ever be used by the Vue app).

Comment: In the tutorial I just linked, the resource server filter chain is used because the REST API is exposed publicly and secured with tokens. The OAuth2 client is a `@FeignClient` used by MVC controllers rendering Thymeleaf templates. It could as well be a batch using `cliernt_credentials` flow. If your only frontend is a SPA, then you could configure your REST API as an OAuth2 client with login (an sessions) instead of a stateless resource server.

Comment: `securityMatcher` defines which filter-chain processes a request. All filter-chains a tried in `@Order` and the first matching is used. `authorizeHttpRequests` is used after the filter-chain was selected and takes an access decision.

Comment: I agree with you that my scenario should actually not require a `resource-server` as the frontend is just a Vue application sending a `JSESSION` cookie. I updated my code according to your tutorials and it basically works fine. There is, however, one thing I don't understand: For testing, I configured the Keycloak token to be valid for only 20 seconds (`SSO Session Idle`). But it seems as if Spring keeps the session alive for much longer. How does the session lifetime correlate with the Keycloak token's expiration?